# Scrolling in CollectionView does not maintain Switch toggle selection

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, collectionview

I have the following `CollectionView` -

```
<CollectionView x:Name="PCollection" ItemsSource="{Binding P.data}" Margin="0,10,2,10">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout>
                <Image Source="p" HeightRequest="60" WidthRequest="60" />
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" >
                    <Label Text="{Binding id}" VerticalOptions="Center" IsVisible="False"/>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" >+
                    <Switch IsToggled="{Binding IsOwned, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalOptions="Start" Toggled="Switch_Toggled_Place" />
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

With my code behind -

```
bool _isOwned;
public bool IsOwned
{
    get
    {
        return _isOwned;
    }
    set
    {
        _isOwned = value;

    }
}

private void Switch_Toggled_Place(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e)
{

}
```

My issue is that when I toggle a switch in the collection, everything works as expected and I step into `Switch_Toggled_Place`. However say there are 20 items in the collection, when I scroll up and the toggled switch goes out of view, for some reason it fires the `Switch_Toggled_Place` again and unchecks my switch!

I have tried removing the `Mode=TwoWay` from the binding to no effect. I also tried to establish if the toggle event was happening from a user input or from the code itself firing but again to no effect. How can I resolve this I am sure it is straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement the interface `INotifyPropertyChanged`

#### in your model

```
public partial class MyModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

   bool _isOwned;
   public bool IsOwned
   { 
     get
     {
        return _isOwned;
     }
     set
     {
        if(_isOwned!=value)
            {
                _isOwned= value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsOwned));

            }

      }
}
```

And since you had used MVVM , you should handle the logic in ViewModel instead of Event . Otherwise it will have conflict with the data-binding .

#### in your ViewMNodel

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    // MySource here is the ItemsSource of CollectionView
    public ObservableCollection<MyModel> MySource { get; set; }


    public MyViewModel()
    {
        MySource = new ObservableCollection<MyModel>() {

       //...
        };

        foreach(MyModel model in MySource)
        {
            model.PropertyChanged += Model_PropertyChanged;
        }

    }

    private void Model_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.PropertyName== "IsOwned")
        {
          // do some thing you want here .
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see I am not using the correct design pattern, I will implement this and report back.

Answer (score 2):

According to this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8416), which is a suggestion to add an OnClick Event to the Switch, people are having the same problem has you.

With that said, as a workarround, you could add a StackLayout on top of the switch with TapGesture to Register the tap, and then Toggle/UnToggle the Switch, removing the need for the Toggled Event

Ex:

```
<Grid>
    <Switch IsToggled="{Binding IsOwned}"></Switch>
    <StackLayout>
        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer 
                Tapped="OnSwitchTapped" 
                NumberOfTapsRequired="1">
        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
    </StackLayout>
</Grid>

...

public void OnSwitchTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Change Switch IsToggle
    //add code here
}
```

It's a very simple example but you get the idea of what you need to do. this is by no means a good solution, it's a workarround, the way you were doing is correct

Comment: I will give this a go shortly and report back!

Comment: @Ebikeneser also take a look at Lucas answer, i assumed that your event fired without user interaction and that Switch_Toggled_Place fired some code you didn't wanted and not because your bindings weren't correct, either way you always have this solution if you don't successed

Comment: Simple and effective.  I have a CollectionView with a SwipeView as the DataTemplate and a toggle as one of the view elements within the Swipe.  
When scrolling the collection, the Toggled event was triggering repeatedly, on android at least, using Xamarin.Forms v5 prerelease 2.  This work around for the bug accomplishes the same task as toggled.